# In the Forestry mod, how do you input seed oil into the carpenter?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I've started using the mod Forestry, and I want to build a bee hive. But this requires a part made from in a carpenter, using wood and some "seed oil".

[image]

I've powered the carpenter, but the liquid part remains empty, even when I put a seed oil can.

What am I missing ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Carpenter can only process liquids that are stored in its tank. To this end, you have two solutions:

1. Simply pipe the liquid from your squeezer to the carpenter.
2. Place the cans in [the top-right-most slot (that is marked with a water drop)](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki/index.php?n=Items.ImpregnatedCasing).

As with water, seed oil should be able to be pumped into the carpenter from any side.

Also, make sure you are running the latest version of Forestry. The ability to use seed oil in the carpenter is a *very* new feature.

<strike>As a sidenote, you don't need an alveary to use bees. Apiaries are more than sufficient for starting out.</strike> Ignore this, I didn't notice the updated recipes in the latest version.

Comment: I see.. But I've put a can of seed oil in the carpenter, 8 logs of wood, powered the motor next to it, and nothing gets made.

Comment: @Manu: Did you put the can into the top slot that is the liquid input slot? It should get destroyed and fill the tank a little. If it doesn't, then try breaking the carpenter and replacing it to clear the tank (You can't put oil in if there is some water in the tank). If it still doesn't work, then it sounds like a bug.

Comment: @Manu: Also, if it still doesn't work then try editing in a screenshot of your crafting window that you think should work.

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug. In the meantime you can use a squeezer to squeeze your cans back into liquid. You may want to simply pipe the liquid around long term though.

Comment: @Manu: You could try posting on the Forestry forum about it too: http://www.mod-buildcraft.com/forums/forum/sub-mods-and-texture-packs/sirsengirs-forestry/ I'm sure SirSengir watches there for bugs, I couldn't see a public bug reporting facility on his website.

Comment: @Manu: Just before you do post a bug though, I noticed you're on Tekkit. Just make sure that you actually have the correct recipe. You only need these in the very, very latest version of forestry, which you likely aren't running.

Comment: I just thought of that :D If the recipe is very new, I may not have the latest version.

Comment: You were right, the server is only on Forestry 1.4.8.6_bc2.2 :(

Comment: @Manu: See my updates in the answer :)

Comment: @Matthew, thank you for referencing Fermat's Theorem. I appreciate you. xD

Answer (score 1):

A [Carpenter](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki/index.php?n=Machines.Carpenter) needs to be powered *and* provided with water. The seed oil is part of the Impregnated Casing crafting recipe, not part of the Carpenter's operation requirements. The liquid gauge is for water, which has to be provided by pipes.

> Items can be piped into the Carpenter using Buildcraft pipes or will be automatically used from adjacent chests. Cartons and Crates can be piped in to the top, all crafting matrix items go in through the side, and **water can be piped into any side**.

Comment: This applies for seed oil too. Seed oil is used in some of the (very) new recipes (such as the casings) *instead* of water, not as well as water I believe.

Comment: @Matthew Ah! Then it should be… put in a tank and piped in, I guess?

Comment: I have discovered an answer, but it won't fit in this comment box.

Answer (score 1):

Check when you hover your curser over the liquid gauge what does it say.  Seed oil or water?  If it says water just break it and put it back up.  I think it's a glitch where it "remembers" the last thing you put in even if its empty.

I'm not looking at the recipe in the listings right this moment im not logged on, but check the wood as well.  Might only work with certain wood

Comment: Hello and welcome to gaming.stackexchange.com. While we appreciate your answers and any constructive help you provide, adding "And please visit my youtube channel and watch my videos so I get paid for the ads" to every comment is very much toeing the line between being helpful and spamming.

Comment: I've just checked with the other moderators, and the answer to this question may be helpful to you if you want to advertise your services here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109680/how-can-i-advertise-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using the correct mod's seed oil.

My carpenter wasn't taking the seed oil I created, so I looked through my TMI to see if it will give me any clues. I noticed that I have two types of seed oil in my mod pack and created the wrong one.